# How do I generate Unique Username using TSQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to generate unique Login username for each users in my system.

What I have done so far is:

```
Select p.FirstName+P.LastName + p.PersonId from person As P
```

> Here `1255` is Primary Key. The Output is like `JamesHarley1255` ,
>   However  I don't want to use the Primarykey. What are other
>   alternatives.There will be numerous Duplicate Records too.
>   Lets say I need a function that generates a unique number everytime between 1 to n numbers. And somehow I need to produce output like JamesHarley125

Comment: What is the actual requirement? You need unique-names in your query or as new primary key? If you only combine firstname+lastname you get duplicates which you want to avoid. Why can't you add the primary-key? Why can't you use `DISTINCT`, what is the goal?

Comment: I need Unique Username without using Primary key. Lets say I need a function that generates a unique number everytime between 1 to n numbers.
And   somehow I  need to produce output like JamesHarley125.

Comment: How is it possible that using the primary key you get any kind of duplicate? Explain this, please.

Comment: I haven't mentioned other unique columns in my table. I have different unique columns such as citizenship number, pan number too. I have updated the question. Please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
    Select p.FirstName+P.LastName +CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.FirstName) AS VARCHAR(20)) 
    from  person As P
```

Comment: Instead of `ORDER BY p.FirstName` i'd use `ORDER BY FirstName,LastName,PersonId`, otherwise you have arbitrary numbers on the duplicates

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get one unique column against each record without using primary key column, I think you can use Row Number function. Query below should work in this case

```
Select p.FirstName+P.LastName + CAST((row_number() OVER ( PARTITION BY p.FirstName ORDER BY p.FirstName)) AS varchar(100)) from person As P
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an column with incremental integers using identity property and you can concatenate the same with the first name and last name. So that each row will be unique.

> Select p.FirstName+P.LastName + P.Id from person As P

Here column P.Id can declared as below in the table definition. This will start with value '1' and will be incremented in the scale of '1'. Identity(seed, increment)

id int IDENTITY(1,1)

Answer (score 0):

Building off the previous responses, this generates usernames without the numbers where possible, and then only adds numbers to make the usernames unique where actually required.  I know this isn't the exact way you are generating your usernames, but this is how I decided to generate mine.  I just changed the table names to match yours.

```
with Usernames(PersonId, Username) as
(
    select PersonId, 
           left(Firstname, 1) + Middlename + Lastname as Username
      from Person
),
NumberedUserNames(PersonId, Username, Number) as
(
    select PersonId,
           Username,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY Username) as Number
      from Usernames
), 
UniqueUsernames(PersonId, UniqueUsername) AS
(
    select PersonId,
           case when Number = 1 then UserName 
                                else UserName + CAST(Number-1 as VarChar(20))
           End as UniqueUsername
      from NumberedUserNames
)
select PersonId,
       UniqueUsername
  from UniqueUsernames;
```